# Question about load function and json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

It is possible to make something like this?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  success: function(json, json1){ //Question here, can i have more than one?
    $m0 = [];
    $m0.push(parseFloat(json));
    alert($m0); //show 750

    $m1 = [];
    $m1.push(parseFloat(json1));
     alert($m1); // show 320
  }
});
```

and what is expected return in json?

this for example? `[750, 320]` or this `[750] [320]?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible; JSON generally includes only a single top-level value. The standard approach would be to have `test.php` return a JSON array of two values:

```
[750, 320]
```

Your load function would then look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  success: function(json){
    $m0 = [];
    $m0.push(parseFloat(json[0]));

    $m1 = [];
    $m1.push(parseFloat(json[1]));
  },
  // this will ask jQuery to parse the JSON for you;
  // otherwise, your success function will receive the
  // string "[750, 320]" as the argument
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: but the values of json in my case represents two query's.  So, what i done is: echo json_encode($result0); and  echo json_encode($result1); how i can encode in the same array values from different query's?

Comment: Do you mean two database queries? If the data you want to send is in `$result0` and `$result1`, then you can wrap them in an array and echo that: `echo json_encode(array($result0, $result1));`